Any performance differences between using IF with AND in Excel vs COUNTIF?
Wondering about performance differences (if any) between the following:
=IF(AND(A1="Completed",B1="Completed",C1="Completed"),"Completed",
     IF(AND(A1="Not started",B1="Not started",C1="Not started"),"Not started","In Progress"))

vs
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"Completed)=3,"Completed",
     IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"Not started")=3,"Not started","In Progress"))


There are several thousand formulas with this pattern (with tablerefs, in case this matters).

Are the formulas in a table?

=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1)=3,A1,"In Progress") ? (assuming your table doesn't have blank rows since, properly used, tables don't need to have blank rows)


An educated guess (based on similar experiences, but not specifically on the choice between COUNTIF vs. IF/AND functions) is that all else being equal, COUNTIF should be faster.

You can try and observe the difference firsthand, with the use of a timing user-defined function.

If you have several thousand formulas like this, for example because you have several thousand rows between the columns A-C, consider replacing the copy/pasted formulas with a single formula, for example like this:
=BYROW(A1:C5000, 
    LAMBDA(r, LET(a, INDEX(r,1), b, INDEX(r,2), c, INDEX(r,3),
        IF(AND(a="Completed",b="Completed",c="Completed"),"Completed",
          IF(AND(a="Not started",b="Not started",c="Not started"),"Not started",
           "In Progress")
            )
        )
     )
 )





No need to bring out the big guns for such a simple formula i.e. e.g. =IF((A:A="Completed")*(B:B="Completed")*(C:C="Completed"),"Completed",IF((A:A="Not started")*(B:B="Not started")*(C:C="Not started"),"Not started","In Progress")) is almost 3 times more efficient. Of course, adjust the references.

Thanks, indeed your formula is a little simpler, although as an ex-developer I still have a preference for the Lambda style because it's much more controllable and isolated. For example, in your formula the ranges are repeated 6 times, so if it has to be changed, you have to do it everywhere.
